# Handling Navigation in Dart Class Without Flutter BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class ApiClient {
  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  final TokenManager _tokenManager = TokenManager();
  final VoidCallback navigateToLogin;

  ApiClient(this.navigateToLogin) {
    _dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
      onRequest: (options, handler) async {
        // Add the Authorization header with the current access token
        options.headers['Authorization'] =
            'Bearer ${await _tokenManager.getAccessToken()}';
        return handler.next(options);
      },
      onError: (DioException e, handler) async {
        if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
          // If the request returns 401, try refreshing the token and retry the request
          await refreshTokenAndRetryRequest(e, handler, navigateToLogin);
        }
        return handler.next(e);
      },
    ));
  }

  Future<void> refreshTokenAndRetryRequest(DioException e,
      ErrorInterceptorHandler handler, VoidCallback navigateToLogin) async {
    try {
      String? refreshToken = await _tokenManager.getRefreshToken();

      if (refreshToken != null) {
        // Example: Call the server endpoint to refresh the tokens
        Map<String, dynamic> newTokens =
            await refreshAccessTokenFromServer(refreshToken);

        // Save the new tokens
        await _tokenManager.setTokens(
            newTokens['accessToken'], newTokens['refreshToken']);

        // Retry the original request with the new access token
        e.requestOptions.headers['Authorization'] =
            'Bearer ${await _tokenManager.getAccessToken()}';
        return handler.resolve(await _dio.request(e.requestOptions.path!));
      } else {
        // Both tokens have expired, so navigate to the login page
        await _tokenManager.deleteTokens();
        // Navigate to the login page
        navigateToLogin();
      }
    } catch (refreshError) {
      // Handle the error during token refresh (e.g., log out the user)
      throw Exception(
          'Failed to refresh token and retry request: $refreshError');
    }
  }
}
```

This is my ApiClient code for every API request. The code is completly written in dart. Here I have a logic to navigate to login page if there is no token or expired token is identified. The problem here is If i need to route to login page I need to use Navigate function which is available in flutter material library and need a BuildContext. However I need this ApiClient to be a completly dart file. How we manage situations like this? I thought navigatetoLoginPage can be written as a callbackfunction. But the class which instance the ApiClient is also a pure Dart class which cant use BuildContext.

Comment: You have context everywhere in the view layer.  Other layers should not be deciding anything about the view.  You *can* observe changes to *model* data and respond as changes in the view.  I use Riverpod for this all the time.

Comment: I am not using any state management right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global navigator key:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> appNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

put it in material app:

```
MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: appNavigatorKey,
)
```

To navigate to a new screen:

```
appNavigatorKey.currentState?.push(...);
```

and if you want a context, you can get it like this:

```
appNavigatorKey.currentContext!;
```

However, it would be best to avoid using this approach. Instead, consider expanding your knowledge on state management and clean architecture principles.

Comment: what if I'm using go_router? how I can go to login screen?